# SQL Function to Currency Convertion

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

I'm trying to create a function that will do currency conversion based on a table. The table is called ds_exchange_rate and looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the base column contains only USD and currency can be either BRL or MXN, whereas rate is the conversion value from USD to BRL/MXN for that given date.

With the objective of making my queries simpler I tried to create a function that would handle the conversions. The function statment looks like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CONVERT_FROM_TO(
    value NUMERIC, 
    from_currency TEXT, 
    to_currency TEXT, 
    reference_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
)
    RETURN NUMERIC
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS
    $$
    DECLARE
        conversion_rate NUMERIC;
    BEGIN
        IF from_currency = 'USD' THEN 
            SELECT rate
            INTO rate
            FROM ds_exchange_rate 
            WHERE currency = to_currency
            AND date = reference_date;
        
            RETURN value * conversion_rate;
        ELSIF to_currency = 'USD' THEN
            SELECT 1/rate
            INTO rate
            FROM ds_exchange_rate 
            WHERE currency = from_currency
            AND date = reference_date;
        
            RETURN value * conversion_rate;
        END IF;
    END;
    $$;
```

I only want USD <-> BRL/MXN conversions so don't worry about BRL <-> MXN.

When trying to create the function I got some syntax erros at or near the first return and the elsif. I believe it's something with the ";", but I wasn't able to fix it (I'm not used to create SQL functions).

If someone could help out I'd appreciate a lot!

Error Message

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ELSIF"
  Position: 1
```

Comment: Not the cause of the error, but `INTO rate` should be `INTO conversion_rate`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ohh thanks, I changed the variable name and forgot about it

Comment: Just an observation. If you are planning to use this function in the select clause as in select  CONVERT_FROM_TO() as a_value, then that query may suffer performance issues as the amount of data increases. You may want consider a function that returns a table of all possible conversions for a given date range and to's and from's and use the result as an inner or outer join on your main dataset.

Comment: @RossBush Yeah, you're totally right. Just wanted to create this first because for some of my queries are fairly simple. I'll probably have to do a version of what you just said later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors, the reserved word for returning function is "returns"
also your selects should return into your conversion_rate variable, so corrected looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CONVERT_FROM_TO(
    value NUMERIC, 
    from_currency TEXT, 
    to_currency TEXT, 
    reference_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
)
    returns NUMERIC
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS
    $$
    DECLARE
        conversion_rate NUMERIC;
    BEGIN
        IF from_currency = 'USD' THEN 
            SELECT rate
            INTO conversion_rate
            FROM ds_exchange_rate 
            WHERE currency = to_currency
            AND date = reference_date;        
            RETURN value * conversion_rate;
        ELSIF to_currency = 'USD' THEN
            SELECT 1/rate
            INTO conversion_rate
            FROM ds_exchange_rate 
            WHERE currency = from_currency
            AND date = reference_date;        
            RETURN value * conversion_rate;
        END IF;
    END;
    $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce this to a single statement, remove the dependency on the conversion of 'USD' and create a sql function.

```
create or replace function convert_rate(
    value numeric, 
    from_currency text, 
    to_currency text, 
    reference_date date default current_date
    )
  returns numeric
 language sql
as $$
 select case when (base, currency) = (from_currency, to_currency) 
             then round(value * rate,6)
             
             when (base, currency) = (to_currency, from_currency) 
             then round(value / rate,6)
             
             else null 
        end
   from ds_exchange_rate 
  where (base, currency) in ( (from_currency, to_currency), (to_currency, from_currency) )
    and ex_date = reference_date;
$$;
```

This does depend on having only a single set of `base` and `currency` values for a single day. Ie for any date you could have either (base, currency) = ('USD','MXN') or ('MXN','USD'), however you would not want both. This can be handled by creating a unique index that orders base, currency.

```
create unique index one_way_daily_conversion 
on ds_exchange_rate (date,least(base,currency), greatest(currency,base));
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f1a08e88b43fc824c77e93de44694a36).